# why phpUnit test code coverage not working in Symfony2 when including file?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in /home/manivasagam/projects/ProofCentral/src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/AttachmentServiceTest.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:77
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHP   9. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:92
```

Comment: You could format your question so it's more readable and people get more desire to answer it.

Comment: You could add some more information, like the test you want to run and the command you use.

Comment: **phpunit --coverage-text app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php**

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you dont load `bootstrap` file

I put the configuration in the `app/phpunit.xml`

With following xml in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>

    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Controller</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/DataFixtures</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/DependencyInjection</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Form</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Event*</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/Firewall</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

And then run the `phpunit`

```
phpunit --coverage-text app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php --bootstrap path/to/your/app/bootstrap.php.cache
```

Comment: **phpunit test is working when using this command "phpunit -c app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php". But phpunit test code coverage report not working using below command "phpunit --coverage-text app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php". That time only i'm getting that error message..**

Comment: This is my error message :
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in /home/manivasagam/projects/ProofCentral/src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php on line 12
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129

Comment: WebTestCase is in the bootstrap file try to add the bootstrap

Comment: use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\ServiceBundle\Services\CalculatorService;
class CalculatorTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $_kernel;
    private $_container;
    protected function setUp() {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();$this->_kernel = $kernel;
        $this->_container = $this->_kernel->getContainer();
    }
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $optService  = $this->_container->get('CalculatorService');
        $result = $optService->add(30, 13);
        $this->assertEquals(43, $result);
    }
}

Comment: **I think unit test code coverage not consider '_Use_' keyword in symfony.It not included specified class file.Please assist me to fix this issue**

Comment: I found the command :**phpunit --coverage-text -c app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php** Thanks to all.

Comment: But generating html,php not working.**phpunit --coverage-html -c app src/ProofCentral/ServiceBundle/Tests/Services/CalculatorTest.php**